# how do i get my code to calculate the number of place correct place values?

Tags: java

I am not really good at coding and I've been confused in this step where I don't know to make my code read the correct number of place values.

For example I run my code and it generates 5 random numbers then I input 5 random numbers the output of this would be "They share 0 numbers in the right place value.

For example,in order for me to get what I want, I get 5 random generated numbers which are 54123, I input 00123 it would say they hold 3 numbers in the right place value.

//this is what I think something needs to be edited
//This is my whole code on a google doc: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ug1rRNwgZwBAf9kvaeAEFoo81r_W9Br6rRX4xc0fFUk/edit?usp=sharing
//I didn't enter my whole code on this post because I think it is to long and the only part I want is where it can calculate how many numbers in the right place value

```
    System.out.println(s);
    String f = scan.next();

    for(int p=0; p<s.length(); p++) {
        for(int z=0;z<f.length();z++){   
            if (s.substring(p,p+1).equals(f.substring(z,z+1))){
                n++;
            } }}
    int rt= 0;
    for(int p=0; p<s.length(); p++) {
        for(int z=0;z<f.length();z++){

            // this where i count the numbers in the right place
            rt=99;
            } }
    System.out.println(" They share " + rt + " numbers in the right place value");
    System.out.println(" They share " + n + " numbers in common");


    System.out.println("guess number 1");
            if(n ==5){
                System.out.println(" Congratulations you win! ");
                System.exit(0);

            }
```

Comment: Your questions is not clear. Please provide a couple of examples as to what is expected. But that aside, you need to be able to convert your code to a simple and reproducible example. When you do this, first, chances are that you can solve your problem yourself. But if you coudln't, then people here would be happy to help.

Comment: So what's going wrong with your code? For example, what output is it generating for the numbers 54123 and 00123?

Comment: Your question is not clear : (a) What happens when the input and the random numbers are of different length? (b) How is the user entering inputs line after line or all in a single line? (c) Are your random numbers being stored in a String or array? (d) Where is your random generator code?

Answer (score 0):

```
    String generatedNums = "54123";
    String nums = "00123";

    int length = generatedNums.length() <= nums.length() ? generatedNums.length() : nums.length();
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (generatedNums.charAt(i) == nums.charAt(i)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```